# Multiple users on OSX Catalina can not write to shared file

Tags: macos, file-permissions

A text file, *filea.txt*, exists.

It's permissions listed in terminal are as follows:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 user1   wheel      filea.txt
```

In finder, getinfo shows the following:

```
user1 R&W
wheel R&W
everyone R&W
```

The directory in terminal shows as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwt  16 root       wheel  Shared
```

and in Finder/Get Info:

```
system R&W
wheel R&W
everyone R&W
```

When I try to modify and save this file as user2, I receive the following error:

```
The document could not be saved, you do not have permission.
```

What is required to allow a file to be shared r&w among several users (non-admins)?

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was group wheel on folder Shared.

```
drwxrwxrwt root wheel Shared
```

I changed this to the following in terminal:

```
drwxrwxr-x  myadminacct staff Shared
```

Works as expected now. Sticky bit was also creating all files with group of wheel.

Users are under staff group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).